# How to print nested JSON array data in a tabular format?

Tags: json, jq

I want to read the status of clusters and servers inside it.

Below is the sample json file

```
"data": [{
        "id": 7865,
        "timeCreated": 1602589399294,
        "timeUpdated": 1602748892149,
        "name": "gw-ext-1",
        "type": "CLUSTER",
        "status": "RUNNING",
        "multicastEnabled": false,
        "primaryNodeId": 546,
        "servers": [{
            "id": 768,
            "timeCreated": 1602589028419,
            "timeUpdated": 1602747941321,
            "name": "gw-jpg208765-1",
            "type": "SERVER",
            "serverType": "GATEWAY",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "addresses": [{
                "networkInterface": "eng123"
            },
            {
                "networkInterface": "eng124"
            }],
            "clusterId": 098,
            "clusterName": "gw-ext-1",
            "currentClusteringPort": 897,
            "runtimeInformation": {
                "Information": {
                    "runtime": {
                        "name": "abctech",
                        "version": "1.6.8"
                    },
                    "specification": {
                        "vendor": "rrr",
                        "name": "rrrt",
                        "version": "1.8.89"
                    }
                },
                "osInformation": {
                    "name": "LX",
                    "version": "35",
                    "architecture": "klh"
                },
                "mExpirationDate": 098765589283662
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 876,
            "timeCreated": 1602589007370,
            "timeUpdated": 1602748894901,
            "name": "gw-jpg208765-2",
            "type": "SERVER",
            "serverType": "GATEWAY",
            "mVersion": "3.9.1",
            "gaVersion": "3.9.1",
            "agentVersion": "1.9.5",
            "ExpirationDate": 32521996800000,
            "ExpirationDate": 1665661007000,
            "status": "DISCONNECTED",
            "addresses": [{
                "networkInterface": "engg"
            },
            {
                "networkInterface": "engg"
            }],
            "clusterId": 768,
            "clusterName": "gw-ext-1",
            "serverPort": 987,
            "currentClusteringPort": 987,
            "runtimeInformation": {
                "abcInfo": {
                    "runtime": {
                        "name": "abc",
                        "version": "1.2.3"
                    },
                    "specification": {
                        "vendor": "RRR",
                        "name": "RTR",
                        "version": "1.8.0"
                    }
                },
                "osInformation": {
                    "name": "LX",
                    "version": "4.78",
                    "architecture": "eng"
                },
                "ExpirationDate": 8765478999765
            }
        }],
        "visibilityMap": {
            "mapNodes": [{
                "serverId": 765,
                "visibleNodeIds": [765,
                876],
                "unknownNodeIps": []
            },
            {
                "serverId": 876,
                "visibleNodeIds": [765,
                876],
                "unknownNodeIps": []
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 7865,
        "timeCreated": 1602589399294,
        "timeUpdated": 1602748892149,
        "name": "gw-ext-2",
        "type": "CLUSTER",
        "status": "RUNNING",
        "multicastEnabled": false,
        "primaryNodeId": 546,
        "servers": [{
            "id": 768,
            "timeCreated": 1602589028419,
            "timeUpdated": 1602747941321,
            "name": "gw-jpg208766-1",
            "type": "SERVER",
            "serverType": "GATEWAY",
            "status": "RUNNING",
            "addresses": [{
                "networkInterface": "eng123"
            },
            {
                "networkInterface": "eng124"
            }],
            "clusterId": 098,
            "clusterName": "gw-ext-2",
            "currentClusteringPort": 897,
            "runtimeInformation": {
                "Information": {
                    "runtime": {
                        "name": "abctech",
                        "version": "1.6.8"
                    },
                    "specification": {
                        "vendor": "rrr",
                        "name": "rrrt",
                        "version": "1.8.89"
                    }
                },
                "osInformation": {
                    "name": "LX",
                    "version": "35",
                    "architecture": "klh"
                },
                "mExpirationDate": 098765589283662
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 876,
            "timeCreated": 1602589007370,
            "timeUpdated": 1602748894901,
            "name": "gw-jpg208766-2",
            "type": "SERVER",
            "serverType": "GATEWAY",
            "mVersion": "3.9.1",
            "gaVersion": "3.9.1",
            "agentVersion": "1.9.5",
            "ExpirationDate": 32521996800000,
            "ExpirationDate": 1665661007000,
            "status": "DISCONNECTED",
            "addresses": [{
                "networkInterface": "engg"
            },
            {
                "networkInterface": "engg"
            }],
            "clusterId": 768,
            "clusterName": "gw-ext-2",
            "serverPort": 987,
            "currentClusteringPort": 987,
            "runtimeInformation": {
                "abcInfo": {
                    "runtime": {
                        "name": "abc",
                        "version": "1.2.3"
                    },
                    "specification": {
                        "vendor": "RRR",
                        "name": "RTR",
                        "version": "1.8.0"
                    }
                },
                "osInformation": {
                    "name": "LX",
                    "version": "4.78",
                    "architecture": "eng"
                },
                "ExpirationDate": 8765478999765
            }
        }],
        "visibilityMap": {
            "mapNodes": [{
                "serverId": 765,
                "visibleNodeIds": [765,
                876],
                "unknownNodeIps": []
            },
            {
                "serverId": 876,
                "visibleNodeIds": [765,
                876],
                "unknownNodeIps": []
            }]
        }
    }]
```

So in each cluster we have two servers and this json continues to have around 15 clusters.
I want to filter out the status of each cluster and server in below format

```
name            cluster/server status
gw-ext-1        CLUSTER        RUNNING
gw-jpg208765-1  SERVER         RUNNING
gw-jpg208765-2  SERVER         DISCONNECTED
```

similarly for other clusters also.

I tried few things but its not giving me the servers .. it gives only cluster's details

target_id=`echo \$targetIdResponse | ${env.WORKSPACE}/jq -r '.data[] | [.name, .type, .status]'`
OR

target_id=`echo \$targetIdResponse | ${env.WORKSPACE}/jq -r '.data[] | [.name, .type, .status, .servers.name, .servers.type, .servers.status]'`

where $targetIdResponse contains my json data

I want to know how i can filter the above json to get the required data.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do - Does this help - `jq -r '[ "name", "cluster/server", "status" ], ( .data[] | [.name, .type, .status ] ) | @tsv'`

Comment: Hi Inian, thanks.. but this only gives the cluster data..
i need the server details too..(which is nested inside cluster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the header array the required fields in a separate array and put them together in a tabular format using `@tsv`

```
jq -r '[ "name", "cluster/server", "status" ], 
       ( .data[] | [.name, .type, .status]  ), 
       ( .data[].servers[] | [ .name, .type, .status ] ) | @tsv'
```

The requirement was modified since originally posted to have the server information exactly below the cluster information

```
jq -r '[ "name", "cluster/server", "status" ],
       ( .data[] | [.name, .type, .status], ( .servers[] | [.name, .type, .status] ) ) | @tsv'
```